# Restrict CRUD in REST API to owner

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

My api has this routes defined:

```
GET test.com/api/v1/users
POST test.com/api/v1/users
PUT test.com/api/v1/users/{id}
GET test.com/api/v1/users/{id}
DELETE test.com/api/v1/users/{id}
```

Also, i'm using OAuth2 Password authentication so these resources are only available once authenticated.

My point is.. keeping RESTFULL API principles, how should I aproach limiting PUT AND DELETE methods to the actual resource owner?

Basically I don't want anybody except the owner to be able to edit his information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implemented the **authentication** part of your system, meaning your application knows **who** the users are. Now you need to devise an **authorization** sub-system, meaning **what** your users have access to.

As your question is tagged PHP and Laravel, a quick Google search for laravel authorization brings results such as this:

https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4

or

http://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2014-authority-controller-authorization-library-cancan-port

This should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually solved by appending a custom header, with a secret message, identifying the request as `valid`. I do not have any source on this I'm afraid.

Usually headers beginning with an `X` - discarding them from being parsed by other parties. `X-Your-Secret` for example.